# Data analysis in TCSPC for fluorescene decay (reconvolution with measured IRF)

Tags: spectrophotometry, fluorescence, numerical-analysis, phosphorescence

I am trying to understand the data analysis of fluorescence decay counts measured by TCSPC technique, particularly with reconvolution with measured IRF.

I am able to get the fitted counts (given by the software according to the model only in the case of tail fitting and not in the case of reconvolution.

#### Tail fit

The basic model is a multi-exponential decay with y-offset(background-offset).

$$
I(t) = A + \sum_{i}^{N}B_{i}\textrm{e}^{\frac{-t}{\tau_{i}}}
$$

Here $B_{i}$ and $\tau_{i}$ are the pre-exponential and lifetime due to the $i$th component respectively and $A$ is the y-offset.

The fitted parameters for a 2 exponential model ($I(t) = A + B_{1}\textrm{e}^{\frac{-t}{\tau_{1}}} + B_{2}\textrm{e}^{\frac{-t}{\tau_{2}}}$) are.

```
A   =   11.63431
T1 (ns) =   0.221457836
T2 (ns) =   2.69572
B1  =   6618.36
B2  =   644.1506

Time per channel (ns) = 0.026128421     
Data range = 402:1289

Peak count  =   10000
Total count =   190155
```

Here I am able to get the fitted counts in the following example by using these parameters. For example in case of bin no. 405.

```
|    | Bin | Time (ns) | DecayCount | FittedCount |
|----|-----|-----------|------------|-------------|
| 0  | 401 | 10.47750  | 9464       | -           |
| 1  | 402 | 10.50363  | 8462       | 6531.378    |
| 2  | 403 | 10.52975  | 7298       | 5870.6414   |
| 3  | 404 | 10.55588  | 5758       | 5282.8124   |
| 4  | 405 | 10.58201  | 4800       | 4759.7832   |
| 5  | 406 | 10.60814  | 4069       | 4294.3481   |
| 6  | 407 | 10.63427  | 3396       | 3880.1036   |
| 7  | 408 | 10.66040  | 2908       | 3511.3585   |
| 8  | 409 | 10.68652  | 2649       | 3183.0549   |
| 9  | 410 | 10.71265  | 2315       | 2890.698    |
| 10 | 411 | 10.73878  | 2171       | 2630.2929   |
```

I am able to plug in the fitted values of the model parameters in the formula to get the fitted count values for any time $t$.

```
t =  10.58201035 - 10.47749666 = 0.104513682

FittedCount = 11.63431 + 
  (6618.36 * exp(-0.104513682/0.221457836)) + 
  (644.1506 * exp(-0.104513682/2.69572)) = 4759.783
```

#### Reconvolution fit

Here the model is.
$$
I(t) = L(t)\otimes \sum_{i}^{N}B_{i}\textrm{e}^{\frac{-t}{\tau_{i}}}
$$

$$
F(t) = A + B.I(t+\Delta)
$$

Here $B_{i}$ and $\tau_{i}$ are the pre-exponential and lifetime due to the $i$th component respectively, $L(t)$ the instrument response function (IRF), $B$ is the amplitude scaling factor, $\Delta$ is the shift parameter and $A$ is the y-offset.

```
A   =   11.41109
T1 (ns) =   0.191460122
T2 (ns) =   2.626401242
B1  =   0.2411146
B2  =   0.007343028
Shift (ns)  =   -0.158856098

Time per channel (ns) = 0.026128421     
Data range = 398:1289

Peak count (Decay)  =   10000
Total count  (Decay)    =   190155
Peak count (IRF)    =   10000
Total count  (IRF)  =   101269
```

**How to get the fitted counts in the case of reconvolution fit ?**

```
| -  | Bin | Time (ns) | IRFCount | DecayCount | FittedCount |
|----|-----|-----------|----------|------------|-------------|
| 0  | 397 | 10.37298  | 9743     | 5665       | -           |
| 1  | 398 | 10.39911  | 10000    | 7982       | 9757.034    |
| 2  | 399 | 10.42524  | 9776     | 9420       | 9106.409    |
| 3  | 400 | 10.45137  | 8918     | 10000      | 8363.679    |
| 4  | 401 | 10.47750  | 7445     | 9464       | 7626.371    |
| 5  | 402 | 10.50363  | 5922     | 8462       | 6899.12     |
| 6  | 403 | 10.52975  | 4538     | 7298       | 6221.999    |
| 7  | 404 | 10.55588  | 3327     | 5758       | 5582.207    |
| 8  | 405 | 10.58201  | 2450     | 4800       | 5004.482    |
| 9  | 406 | 10.60814  | 1605     | 4069       | 4481.801    |
| 10 | 407 | 10.63427  | 1191     | 3396       | 4012.029    |
```

Specifically, in the calculation, How to

- get the amplitude scaling factor (in addition to the amplitudes) and
- shift the measured IRF using the shift parameter.

I have tried multiplying by the total IRF count value to get the $B_{i}$s corresponding to a tail fit, but still not getting the fitted counts as in the output.

#### Update

Here are the comments regarding scaling of $B_{i}$s by the scaling factor $B$ in few fitting software program documentations.

http://www.nanoer.net/d/img/1-FASTissue6.pdf

> If the fit was performed in the Reconvolution mode, $B_{i}$ values are
> scaled by the integrated IRF, i.e. if the same decay would be analysed
> with a 10 times bigger IRF, the numerical values of the $B_{i}$ values would
> be reduced by a factor of 10. If one determines the total number of
> counts of the IRF, and then multiplies the $B_{i}$ value with this number,
> this will result in a value that will be similar to the $B_{i}$ value for a
> tail fit, extrapolated to the channel of the peak of the IRF.

https://www.horiba.com/fileadmin/uploads/Scientific/Downloads/UserArea/Fluorescence/Manuals/DAS67_Manual.pdf

> The magnitude of the $B_{i}$ values returned in the fit are dependent
> on whether or not reconvolution is used in  fitting  the  data.
> Without  reconvolution  the  values  are  in  counts  and  can  easily
> be  linked  to  the  peak  number  of  counts  (ie  for  a  single
> exponential  its  magnitude  should  be  ~  the  count  value  in  the
> start  channel).  The  value  after  reconvolution  is  not  in
> counts,  but  still  reflects  the  amount  of  a  particular
> emitting species.

Comment: The shift parameter is part of the fitting and is used because different filters/wavelength etc may be used when measuring the irf vs fluorescence so this time delay is adjusted by the convolution process to get a best fit. It has no physical meaning otherwise. The amplitudes $B$ are relative to one another;  the absolute values usually do not matter (as fluorescence yields are not often measured via tcspc), but you can normalise if you wish to get x% B1 and y% B2 etc.

Comment: @porphyrin I understand why shift is used fitted for a reconvolution fit and how $B_i$s are different in case of tail fit vs reconvolution fit. I want to know how to get the fitted counts at a time $t$ by using the fitted parameter values in the model, as I can do with tail fit.

Comment: I don't quite understand, if you use the fitting parameters and convolute the function, formed from two exponentials plus background, with your instrument function your should get the experimental counts.

Comment: @porphyrin Yes, I should be able to get that. But the problem is with the $Bi$s. They are scaled with the amplitude scaling factor $B$, which I am not able to figure out. When I try to fit with other software, I am getting the values for the amplitudes B1 = 16781.47 and B2 = 580.40. The relative amplitude from above are B1 =  0.2411146 and B2 =  0.007343028. But also in both cases the normalised pre-exponential values are identical (B1 = 0.97 and B2 = 0.03).

Comment: It looks as though the background has not been included in the convolution: it is 11.4 but B is 0.24 & 0.007 so something is wrong here. The background should be far smaller , approx 6600 times comparing the fit without and with convolution. Its best to convolute with background because subtracting from a  poisson distributions is never a good idea since negative values are impossible.

Comment: The low values of $B_{i}$s is due to scaling factor $B$ (Check the comments in the update above), not because background was not incorporated into the convolution.

Comment: Your background should be included as a parameter, especially as this can affect the lifetime of any long lived species especially when amount is small, i.e. long lifetime and background can 'interfere' with one another. You should look at the covariance matrix to check this.  BTW, if the convolution uses FFT you must ensure that the data is as close to zero as possible at the start and end of the dataset. (FFT assumes a repetitive signal series so any discontinuity is seen as a feature and messes up analysis, but this is not your present problem)